# Who did Abraham worship?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, abraham

1) How did Abraham worship God? Isn't it a bit inconsistent, since Abraham would not worship Jesus, as technically he is the ancestor of him. So, who did Abraham worship?

2) If he didn't worship Jesus, and if Christianity tells us god is three, how do we know god won't multiplicate into higher numbers than 3 in the future? And if God is perfect, what is the perfectness of three? Why isn't four five six hundred thousand?

Comment: I think there are too many questions here, I'm afraid. It should be possible to distill this to get the information you're really interested in (and probably mention the supplementary stuff as well), but it's not obvious enough what the main question is. If it's simply "Who did Abraham worship," then the answer is "God, as he had revealed himself to Abraham and his people."

Comment: So many questions!

Comment: **Mod notice:** Please do not use the comment function to A) debate theological issues or B) answer questions. If you have an answer, post it as an answer. If all you have is a related verse or quip, please just refrain as it just starts undermining the comment system and drums up discussion of issues. (@: mojo, gideonmarx, davidbrainerd et all)

Comment: Is your question, 'who did ...' or 'how did ...'? The 'who did ...' is too easy to do a whole answer on. The 'how did ...' presents an interesting challenge, so it would be nice if you could clarify.

Comment: cf. [Abraham | Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/origins.htm#Abraham)

Comment: Abraham worshipped YHVH, the God revealed in the Bible, and he worshipped Him primarily with the sacrifice that he may have been taught by God to offer,-or he may have found out about this means, because since the first sin, ie. Adam and Eve, animals blood were shed, ie. God shed animal blood at the first sin, and gave the skins to the first couple to cover themselves with. Before that they did not need extra covering, it is thought they wore garments of light that were the glory of God.

Comment: YHVH said in Gen. in the beginning "Let US make man in OUR image." (implying God consisted of entities that could communicate with each other.)Elsewhere the Bible teaches Jesus and the Holy Spirit are also 'God'.

Comment: @natsirun did you know that the 'sons of God' who are 'joint heirs with Jesus Christ", are God's own family, his sons that are inheriting everything God has? We are legitimate sons, not begotten exactly the way Jesus was, but begotten by the Word of God, making us New Creations in Christ Jesus, and it does not yet appear what we shall be, but we know when we see Him, we shall be "LIKE" him.

Comment: God never changes so always existed, and Abraham worshipped the same God we know today. YHVH.

Answer (score 8):

You have a couple different questions, but the main one seems to be in regard to Abraham and Jesus.

**Abraham and Jesus**

Abraham is only the ancestor of Jesus in His incarnation.  Orthodox, Catholic and Protestant branches of Christianity teach that God is and has always been a Trinity of Father, Son and Spirit.  The Son became a man and entered into His creation around 2000 years ago.  When He did so, He was given the name "Jesus", which means "God saves".  He was named this because He came to save.

However, Jesus, or God the Son, existed "before Abraham".  In fact, it was likely God the Son in a pre-incarnate appearance Who visited Abraham prior to the destruction of Sodom.  He was also likely the fourth Man in the fire with Shadrach, Meshach and Abednego, whom Nebuchadnezzar described as one "like a son of God (the gods)".

Even in creation, God says, "Let **us** make man in **our** image, in **our** likeness..."

So, Abraham did worship God the Son before He became a Man and took on the name of Jesus.

**The Trinity**

Briefly, the Trinity is something that is seen in much of creation.  The physical universe consists of 1) time, 2) space and 3) matter.  The three are co-existent.  Time itself is measured as 1) past, 2) present and 3) future--it is one, yet a distinct three as well.  Space is measured in 1) length, 2) width and 3) height--three distinct dimensions.  Matter exists as 1) solid, 2) liquid and 3) gas, as H2O can be ice, liquid and vapor, yet still the same substance at its atomic level.

So, the concept of a three-in-one unity is not without example in creation itself.  These examples are understood to be reflections of the Creator.

God never divided from One into Three.  He has always been and will always be Father, Son and Spirit.

Comment: Good answer. I think plasma is also considered a [phase of matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter#The_four_fundamental_states) along with solid, liquid, and gas. This doesn't negate your argument about seeing trinities in nature, it just seems like phases of matter are a helpful example.

Comment: The science here is terrible. Your answer does not need it.

Comment: @gideonmarx Any basis for that statement?

Comment: @Narnian Yup. The entire scientific world. Oh, and stuff like mercury. And the number two, as in spin directions, occur billions and billions of times more than three. And God is both creator and eternal, two entities that is one, just like space/time that is one thing and matter that is energy. And space that exist in four dimensions. Why am I answering this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14469/discussion-between-narnian-and-natsirun)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with gideon marx and I would also like to add that it is held christ was Melchizedek, whom Abraham paid tithe to in Genesis 14:18-20

And Melchizedek, the
king of Salem and a priest
of God Most High,
brought Abram some
bread and wine.
Melchizedek blessed
Abram with this blessing:
“Blessed be Abram
by God Most High,
Creator of
heaven and earth.
And blessed be
God Most High,
who has
defeated your
enemies for you.”
Then Abram gave
Melchizedek a tenth of all
the goods he had
recovered.

genesis 14:18-20

also references of this are made in the new testament

The name
Melchizedek means
“king of justice,” and king
of Salem means “king of
peace.” There is no
record of his father or
mother or any of his
ancestors—no beginning
or end to his life. He
remains a priest forever,
resembling the Son of
God. ...

hebrews 7

also

Jesus has already gone
in there for us. He has
become our eternal High
Priest in the order of
Melchizedek.

hebrews6:20

and

The priests who collect
tithes are men who die,
so Melchizedek is
greater than they are,
because we are told that
he lives on.

hebrews 7:8

so in conclusion abraham did acknowledge christ but just not as "Jesus" but he acknowledged christ in another sense because christ at that point was still prophecied to come incarnate as Jesus and save yet he still played a major role throughout the entire sequence of events leading up to his incarnation

Comment: Please see [the formatting options available to you](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) and make good use of them ([edit]).